# Javadoc not generating -- doc folder

Tags: java, javadoc

When I generate a java doc i want all my html files to appear under the doc folder. however it comes like this:
[image]

These were my specifications:
[image: java]

Comment: The destination of the standard doclet has been set to `Lab1`. Change it to `docs`